# Is the following set reflective, symmetric or transitive $R = \{(x,y) : x+ y \leq 2015 , x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

is the following set reflective, symmetric or transitive $R = \{(x,y) : x+ y \leq 2015 , x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

The set is transitive as $(1,2)$ is there $(2,1)$ is there and $(1,1)$ is there and so on..
It is reflective as $(1,1) \;\; (2,2)$ will be there an so on.. 
It is symmetric because $(1,2)$ will be there and $(2,1)$ will be there and so on.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

$(2000, 2000) \notin R$ - so $R$ is not reflective.

$(2000, 10) \in R$ and $(10, 2000) \in R$, but as noted above, $(2000, 2000) \notin R$, so $R$ is not transitive.

$R$ is symmetric, though - $(x, y) \in R \iff x + y \leq 2015 \iff y + x \leq 2015 \iff (y, x) \in R$.

Comment: But 2000 + 2000 is greater than 2015 so wouldn't be in the set would it?

Comment: That's the point. $R$ is reflexive iff $(a, a) \in R$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Taking $a = 2000$ shows this isn't true.

Comment: okay i see brillant cheers